# How i can access list of data which is in sender object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

```
private void TrendicProductClick(object sender, int position)
{
}
```

This is my method which gives me sender and position.
I want to get _DealList which is in side "non-public member" of sender.
my sender hierarchy is something like this =>

1. sender

   - Base
   - ItemCount
   - Non-Public Members

     - _DealList

**I want to access data of** `_DealList`

Comment: What type is `sender`, can you show that class? Why don't you make this `_DealList` public or provide a method to do what you want?

Comment: Because of some reason i cannot make list public thats why wants to access from here

Comment: You shouldn't make it public but why can't you provide a method that encapsulates the action that you want to do? The obvious answer for your question is reflection. But that should be the very last resort

Comment: @TimSchmelter how i can implement reflection in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the private properties of the sender, as @Tim suggested we need to use `Reflection`

e.g. let us suppose the type of sender is `MyClass` and has the following structure, then you can get the property by doing this. I'm assuming that `dealList` is public. Otherwise you can use Reflection for that also:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
        FooBar(myObj);
    }
    public static void FooBar(object sender)
    {
        Type t = typeof(MyClass);
        var info = t.GetField("deal",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var dealObject = info?.GetValue(sender);
        var dealListObj = ((DealList) dealObject)?.dealList;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private DealList deal = new DealList();
    public void Foo() { }
}

public class DealList
{
    public List<int> dealList = new List<int>() {2,3};
}
```

Comment: i did something like this   var info = sender.GetType().GetField("_DealList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var dealObject = info?.GetValue(sender);